# Elementor Toggle closes when another open not working in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, elementor

I have this code which works great in chrome but not working at all in safari.

Could you please let me know if I'm missing anything to make this work in safari?

Basically when a toggle is open and I open another one in the page the previous one closes.
It doesn't work in safari

```
    <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.elementor-toggle .elementor-tab-title').click(function() {
            var $thisToggle = $(this);
            var $allToggles = $('.elementor-toggle .elementor-tab-title');

            // Close all other toggles except the one clicked
            $allToggles.not($thisToggle).each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('elementor-active');
                $(this).next('.elementor-tab-content').slideUp();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Thank you